# How to define entire database schema in Symfony 4?

Tags: symfony, doctrine, symfony4

Is there a way to define the complete database schema in one go in Symfony 4?

I understand that individual entities/objects can be created using the `make:entity` and `make:migration` commands but I'm wondering if I could just define the entire schema in one sitting and then use it to build the associated entities and database.

I recall that in earlier versions of Symfony it was possible to define the entire schema in a YAML file and then just issue a build command.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you can create complete database schema mappings using any of supported mapping formats (e.g. YAML or XML) and [declare mappings location](https://symfony.com/doc/current/bundles/DoctrineBundle/configuration.html#mapping-configuration) in Doctrine configuration. After that you will be able to use any Doctrine [console tools](https://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/2.6/reference/tools.html#tools) to generate and update schema. You can also use tools for [reverse engineering](https://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/2.6/reference/tools.html#reverse-engineering) mappings from already available database and to [convert](https://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/2.6/reference/tools.html#convert-mapping-information) mappings between formats

Please notice that Doctrine commands names in Symfony application are different from ones that natively provided by Doctrine. You need to use:

- `doctrine:schema:validate` for schema validation
- `doctrine:schema:create` for initial schema generation with subsequent calls of `doctrine:schema:update` with either `--dump-sql` or `--force` depending on your needs
- `doctrine:mapping:convert` to reverse engineer available database (with use of `--from-database` option) or convert between mapping types in a case if you want to.